# C++ (básico): for, referências e sintaxe

Tags: c++, for, sintaxe, c++11, referência

Meu professor apresentou essa função para a gente:

```
void escala(std::vector<double> &v, double fator)

{
    for (auto &vi:v){
    vi *= fator;
    }
}
```

Ela serve pra multiplicar todos os elementos de um vetor por um fator já pré-definido.

**Tenho 2 dúvidas:**

> **1**. Eu entendi o porquê de o vetor v ser passado como referência no argumento da função. Entretanto, porque 'vi', dentro do 'for', é passado como referência também? (caso contrário, não funciona, já testei)
>
> **2**. Alguém pode me explicar como funciona essa sintaxe alternativa do 'for'? Talvez seja até por não entender tão bem que estou com a dúvida 1. Não achei nada na internet sobre, aparece sempre a sintaxe padrao 'for( ; ; )'.

Answer (score 8):

Pra responder a primeira pergunta, podemos começar pela segunda, que tornará os motivos da primeira mais óbvios.

A construção (chamada de [*range-based for*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), ou *for baseado em intervalo*):

```
 for (declaração : expressão) corpo
```

É apenas açúcar sintático e é transformada para a seguinte construção:

```
{
    auto && __range = expressão ;
    auto __begin = begin_expr; // normalmente begin_expr é begin(__range)
    auto __end = end_expr; // normalmente end_expr é end(__range)
    for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
        declaração = *__begin;
        corpo
    }
}
```

> **Note** que essa transformação é conformante com [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17).

Essa versão do `for` funciona com qualquer *expressão* que possa ser iterada. No seu exemplo, `std::vector` pode ser iterado, pois ele possui as funções membro `std::vector::begin` e `std::vector::end`, que retornam iteradores para o começo do vetor e para o fim, respectivamente. Por exemplo:

```
#include <cassert>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
    int soma = 0;
    for (int i : v)
        soma += i;
    assert(6 == soma);
}
```

Se pegarmos apenas a parte do `for` do exemplo acima, vemos que

- `int i` é a *declaração*,
- `v` é a *expressão* e
- `soma += i;` é o *corpo*.

Na transformação (um pouco mais simplificada), teremos:

```
{
    auto __begin = begin(v);
    auto __end = end(v);
    for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
        int i = *__begin;
        soma += i;
    }
}
```

Perceba que a parte `int i = *__begin` é onde cada elemento do intervalo (o vetor `v` nesse caso) é atribuído para a variável `i`. O corpo do `for` vem em seguida.

O *`for` baseado em intervalo*, como dito antes, funciona com qualquer intervalo. Portanto, qualquer contêiner que seja possível conseguir um iterador de seu começo e fim funcionará com essa construção do `for` (e.g. *arrays* de tamanho fixo, alguns contêiner da biblioteca padrão, como `std::map`, `std::vector`, `std::array` etc).

Se o conceito *iterador* não é familiar, veja-o como um objeto que consegue percorrer os elementos de um contêiner. Por exemplo, um ponteiro pro primeiro elemento do vetor pode ser considerado um iterador, pois quando vamos incrementando esse ponteiro, vamos conseguindo acesso para os elementos em sequência daquele vetor, até chegar no fim, que é um ponteiro para depois do último elemento (significando a chegada, ou fim da iteração). Nesse caso, `__begin` e `__end` seriam tais iteradores, onde `__begin` tem acesso ao primeiro elemento (e é incrementado durante o laço, pra acessar os elementos seguintes) e `__end` representa o fim da iteração. Quando `__begin` for igual a `__end`, significa que o laço terminou e todos os elementos foram iterados.

Voltando pra primeira pergunta, vemos que agora é óbvio o porquê declaramos `vi` como uma referência. Se olharmos seu exemplo:

```
for (auto &vi : v) {
    vi *= fator;
}
```

Temos `auto &vi` como *declaração*, `v` como *expressão* e `vi *= fator` como `corpo`:

```
{
    auto __begin = begin(v);
    auto __end = end(v);
    for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
        auto &vi = *__begin;
        vi *= fator;
    }
}
```

Quando atribuímos os elementos do vetor `v` em cada iteração, conseguimos a *referência* para aquele elemento. Se tivéssemos a *declaração* como apenas `auto vi` (ou `double vi`), estaríamos copiando o elemento para a variável `vi`. Já que o intuito é modificar o elemento, uma cópia não funcionaria, nós queremos acesso de escrita ao elemento, então a referência é usada.

> **Atenção**, o uso de `__` como prefixo dos nomes são reservados pela padronização. Não escreva nomes assim por conta própria, pois eles são usados exatamente pra impedir que código de usuário entre em conflito com código da biblioteca padrão, açúcares sintáticos ou funções intrínsecas do compilador.

Answer (score 5):

1. Porque você precisa continuar mantendo a referência para o objeto dentro do código. Se você não usar `&vi` no `for`, não irá alterar o objeto original que foi passado por referência, mas uma cópia dele existente dentro do `for` apenas.
2. Essa construção chama-se *range-based* e é usada para percorrer todos os itens do array, semelhando ao comando `foreach` existente em outras linguagens.  Simplificando, seria como dizer *"para cada item de `&v`, usar a variável `vi`"*, ou seja, em cada interação do `for` um elemento será associa à varíavel `vi`, como se fosse:

`vi = &v[0]`, `vi = &v[1]`, e assim por diante.

Mais sobre *range-based loop* você pode ler aqui:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/jj203382.aspx