# Como percorrer um set com dados inseridos?

Tags: c++, c++11, dev-c++

eu tenho um programinha que insere alguns inteiros em um set, e remove quando encontrar um igual, após fazer isso, eu preciso trazer na saída todos os inteiros que ainda estão dentro do set, porém eu não estou conseguindo fazer para percorrer o set e trazer a informação que quero. Segue o código:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream> 
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main (){

int n,k,x;
set <int> di;
set <int>:: iterator it;

cin>>n;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    cin>>k;
    for (int j=0; j<k; j++){
        if (i!=0){
            cin>>x;
            it = di.find(x);
            if (it!=di.end())
                di.erase(it);
        }
        else{
            cin>>x;
            di.insert(x);
        }
    }
}
it = di.begin();
while(it!=di.end()){
    cout<<&it;
    di.erase(it);
    it++;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você está iterando no seu `std::set` e alterando o conteúdo deste container ao mesmo tempo (removendo itens). A remoção de elementos invalida o iterador que você está usando no momento, mas o método `iterator erase( const_iterator pos )` retorna um iterador válido para você continuar iteração. Você precisa então fazer o seu iterador igual ao retorno da função erase para que a iteração continue.

Além disso, você pode pensar no iterador como um ponteiro e, por isso, para imprimir seu valor você deve dereferenciá-lo como `*it` e não `&it`.

```
it = di.begin();
while(it!=di.end()){
    cout << *it << " "; // *it no lugar de &it e um espaço para separar os itens
    it = di.erase(it); // o iterador retornado pelo erase aqui é o próximo item do seu set
    //it++; -> não funciona quando está removendo o item durante a iteração, porque a remoção do item com o erase invalida o iterador corrente
}
```

Não é necessário remover itens do set para imprimí-los. Você poderia apenas usar um range-based for loop como o colega da reposta anterior mencionou, ou mesmo usar o iterador da forma que estava fazendo:

```
it = di.begin();
while(it != di.end()) {
    cout << *it << " ";
    it++;
}
```

Uma dica não relacionada a pergunta é tentar usar nomes de variáveis mais significativos. *n, k, x, di* são nomes curtos que não dizem nada sobre o que são suas variáveis e tornam seu código difícil de ler e entender.

Answer (score 1):

Para percorrer qualquer contêiner da biblioteca padrão de C++, você pode usar [range-based for](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/296790/c-b%c3%a1sico-for-refer%c3%aancias-e-sintaxe/296813#296813):

```
for (auto elemento : contêiner)
    faz_algo(elemento);
```

No seu caso, o contêiner em questão é um `std::set`. A ideia é a mesma:

```
std::set<int> di{1, 2, 3};
for (int x : di)
    std::cout << x << '\n'; // imprime 1, 2 e 3.
```